# Retrieve local/network PostgreSql servers

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

Is any ways to retrieve local/network PostgreSql servers names in c# application?
I mean something like SQL Server method:

```
 instances = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();
```

Comment: Have you found out the answer?

Comment: There are no universal ways. By the way the SQL Server's approach does work but not always. For example, the SQL Browser service should work, also it does not work for LANS with multiple domains (trusted or partially trusted) etc

Comment: I tried the SQL Server approach with a Docker instance of PostgreSQL and got nothing. Thanks for the answer anyways!